# React - send function props to Children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, parent-child

I saw some questions speaking about similar issues but somehow I still do not manage to solve my issue so here I am asking for your kind help. I am pretty new to React and would like to send a function from a Parent to a child and then use it from the Child but somehow when I want to use it it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Edited Code after first answers were helping:

```
var Menu = React.createClass({
    links : [
        {key : 1, name : "help", click : this.props.changePageHelp}
    ],
    render :    function() {
        var menuItem = this.links.map(function(link){
            return (
                <li key={link.key} className="menu-help menu-link" onClick={link.click}>{link.name}</li>
            )
        });
        return (
            <ul>
                    {menuItem}
            </ul>
        )
    }
});

var Admin = React.createClass ({
    _changePageHelp : function() {
        console.log('help');
    },
     render : function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="menu-admin"><Menu changePageHelp={this._changePageHelp.bind(this)} /></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Admin />, document.getElementById('admin'));
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post that I just want the console.log('help') to activate which doesnt. The nice answer belowed focus on the fact I didn't send the function a parameter however I just want to activate the function and it does not seem to be working (still the undefined error)

Comment: Ok partly works thanks to comment below, my problem seems to be elsewhere afterall. I also wanted in my shild component to create a variable like this :  links : [
  {key : 1, name : "help", click : this.props.changePageHelp}
 ], and it doesnt seem to like it because tht's when my error appears. Can't I use the props sent in a variable in my Child component ?

Comment: The answers below address some of your code issues, but they don't actually fix your error which seems to be related to the fact that `this` doesn't have a `prop` property - probably because the wrong `this` is being referenced. Try using ES6 arrow functions. That will prevent that headache.

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe where exactly you have a problem

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri : just did so. Idea was to create links though components but somehow something doesn't wanna pass through. There will be more than one "links" as you can expect

Comment: @Ivo, I've just updated my answer to improve performance of your app. Does it solve you questions?

Comment: It does, I marked it as right answer, thanks a lot. Though still don't get why it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons, you should avoid using `bind` or arrow functions in JSX props. This is because a copy of the event handling function is created for every instance generated by the `map()` function. This is explained here: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

To avoid this you can pull the repeated section into its own component. Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/EgvjmZ The `console.log()` call in your parent component receives now the name of the link. You could use it for example in React Router.

```
var Admin = React.createClass ({
    _changePageHelp : function(name) {
      console.log(name);
    },

    render : function () {
      return (
        <div>
          <div id="menu-admin">
            <Menu changePageHelp={this._changePageHelp} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
});


var Menu = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      links: [
        {key: 1, name: 'help'},
        {key: 2, name: 'about'},
        {key: 3, name: 'contact'}
      ]
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    var menuItem = this.props.links.map((link) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem key={link.key}
                  name={link.name}
                  changePageHelp={this.props.changePageHelp}
                  className="menu-help menu-link" />
      );
    });

    return (
      <ul>
        {menuItem}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});


var MenuItem = React.createClass ({
  handleClick: function() { 
    this.props.changePageHelp(this.props.name);
  },

  render : function () {
    return (
      <li onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click me to console log in Admin component <b>{this.props.name}</b>
      </li>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(<Admin />, document.getElementById('admin'));
```

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot ! However I still do not really understand why the other solutions were not working...

Answer (score 2):

Pass a value from Menu function and recieve it in the changePageHelp function and it works.

```js
var Menu = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.changePageHelp('Hello')}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Admin = React.createClass ({
    _changePageHelp : function(help) {
        return help;
    },
     render : function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="menu-admin"><Menu changePageHelp={this._changePageHelp.bind(this)} /></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Admin />, document.getElementById('admin'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="admin"></div>
```